# Why I can't see the png from the other side of the glass?

Tags: unity-game-engine, png, transparency

I've been modeling glassware and making the labels for school assignment, but when I join them in Unity, the label is visible only in front of the flask. What do I need to make it visible from all directions?

How I want:

[image]

How it is:

[image]

Comment: There are a number of potential problems ranging from "how the object is UV'd" to "is it double sided" and so on.

Comment: Most probably because of [Backface culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling). Your model needs to be solid/double sided